# Django urls.py error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nodejs, django

Estoy intentando meter el `MEDIA_ROOT` en el archivo `urls.py` pero cuando ejecuto el comando `python manage.py runserver` me aparece el siguiente error:

```
File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\static.py", line 24, in static
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted") django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Empty static prefix not permitted
```

Este es mi archivo `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from boletin.views import inicio


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', inicio, name='inicio')
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Aquí está mi archivo `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", "static_root")

STATIC_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", "media_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_pro", "static"),
]
```

Así es mi árbol de directorios:

[image: ArbolDirectorios]

Os pongo el error completo que me da el comando `python manage.py runserver`:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x000000000469C3C8> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
```

Espero vuestra ayuda, un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Manuel, verifica que resuelve esta línea: `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", "media_root")`

Comment: Supuestamente si resuelve esa línea, no da ningún error. He modificado el post con el error completo que me da.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me costó bastante encontrar el error, pero lo encontré:

Este es tu código (acabo de copiarlo y pegar):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", "static_root")

STATIC_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", "media_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_pro", "static"),
]
```

Revisando un poco el código de Django, y fuí a la linea exacta donde tira el error, es [esta](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.17/django/conf/urls/static.py#L25): y veo que la única forma que te salga ese error, es que no estes enviando una variable con algún valor.

Ahora, si ves tu código, verás que tienes `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` y mas abajo tienes nuevamente `STATIC_URL = '/media/'`, lo cual quiere decir que nunca definiste en tu settings la variable `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`, por lo que django al crearla por defecto, la tiene vacia (`''`), y dado esto es que se genera el error. Está de más decir que para solucionarlo debes cambiar el segundo `STATIC_URL = '/media/'` por `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Cualquier duda, pregunta, comenta :)

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, es lógico estoy machacando el valor de 'STATIC_URL' al final se quedaría con el valor de '/media/' y tampoco estoy creando ninguna variable que sea 'MEDIA_URL' , la verdad es que lo vi raro, estoy siguiendo un curso en Youtube y lo tenían así y les funcionaba, no se cómo. Gracias por la ayuda, un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Probá cambiando esto:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', inicio, name='inicio')
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Por la forma oficial de la documentación:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', inicio, name='inicio')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Recuerda que esta configuración en producción debe delegarse al servidor a través de la configuración que te provea el hosting.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Me tira el mismo error poniéndolo de esa manera, comentando la línea de la 'media_url' si me tira bien el servidor sin errores, pero quiero saber porque me da ése error, gracias por la respuesta de todas formas.